# Does java.util.regex cache the compiled patterns?

Tags: java, regex

From [PCRE Introduce](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pcre.php)

> This extension maintains a global per-thread cache of compiled regular expressions (up to 4096).

How about `java.util.regex`, will this cache the compiled patterns?

Because sometimes I just don't want to introduce too many variables to store patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How about java.util.regex, will this cache the compiled patterns?

Not in Java 6 or 7 ... according to the source code.

My memory was that the static `Pattern.compile(...)` methods *did* implement a small cache, but presumably that feature was removed in / by Java 6.

If you want to implement `Pattern` caching in Java, you can do it yourself in a variety of ways.  (Alternatively, Googling for "java regex cache" gave me some useful hits ...)

Answer (score 0):

If you create a `Pattern` object, it compiles the regular expression, and as long as you hold that object, it is "cached" for further use. You can make your application even more efficient by [using a single `Matcher` object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951558/regex-optimization-for-large-lists/22951636#22951636).